# Insert sequential row and column values automatically into a fishnet dataset

Tags: qgis, mapinfo, vector-grid

I have a grid that has about 30 rows with approx 15 columns each.

I want to label them as A1,A2,B1,B2 etc (Alphabet row, integer is column). Is there any way to do this programatically?

There is no fixed number of columns in a row, so we can not say that after every x columns the next item is B etc.

If necessary I guess we can compare the y on the top right of each grid and when it changes Row A becomes B but I am hoping that there is an easier way of doing this in SQL (Mapinfo) or QGIS.

Unfortunately, I don't have access to ArcGIS grid tool that does this.

I used "QGIS--Vector--Research--Vector Grid" to make the grid.

Another way of asking this is, can this QGIS tool be modified to include grid numbering like in the ArcGIS equivalent [Grid Index Features (Cartography)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Grid_Index_Features/00700000000q000000/) and also ideally the [surrounding map numbers](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Calculate_Adjacent_Fields/007000000009000000/).

I am also happy to use a mapbasic program to do this.

Comment: Could you use the coordinates to determine what row/column a certain cell is at? I would image that the cells are of a specific width/height which could be used to determine "how far away" from the start point a given cell is

Comment: @PeterHorsbøllMøller yes this could work and I included this in my question but I am hoping that someone already has a solution for this. It would be great to look at the code behind the arcgis tools mentioned to see what they did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pyqgis with the string and collections.defaultdict libraries.

Add a field named `label` of string/text type, change `Grid` to the name of your layer below and execute:

```py
import string
from collections import defaultdict as dd

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Grid')[0]
features = [f for f in layer.getFeatures()] #List all features
features.sort(key=lambda x: x.geometry().centroid().asPoint().y(), reverse=True) #Sort by y coordinate

rows = dd(list) #Create a defaultdict list which will have y coordinate (/the row identifier) as key and all features in that row as a list

for feature in features: 
    rowid = round(feature.geometry().centroid().asPoint().y())
    rows[rowid].append(feature)
# {6901627: [<qgis._core.QgsFeature object at 0x7f7804a1a160>,..., 
# 6896627: [<qgis._core.QgsFeature object at 0x7f7804a1a550>, <qgis._core.QgsFeature object at 0x7f7804a11af0>,

for rowid, featurelist in rows.items(): #Now sort each feature list by x coordinate
    rows[rowid] = sorted(rows[rowid], key=lambda x: x.geometry().centroid().asPoint().x())

fieldindex = layer.fields().indexFromName('label')
attributemap = {}
for row, letter, (_, features) in zip(rows, string.ascii_uppercase, rows.items()): #For each row
    for e, feature in enumerate(features, 1): #For each feature in the rows list of ids
        attributemap[feature.id()] = {fieldindex:letter+str(e)} #Store feature id and row letter and number as value
#attributemap is now 0: {1: 'A1'}, 3: {1: 'A2'}, 11: {1: 'A3'}, ...
layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(attributemap)
```

(The code became complicated because I removed some grid cells):

[image]

Comment: in QGIS 3.25 I am getting `Windows fatal exception: access violation`. Is there an easy fix to using this code in 3x. I assume your answer was for v2x as it's 6y old now.

Comment: This crashes Qgis 3.32.1 Windows 11 :-(

Comment: It is working for me on Windows 11 QGIS 3.28. Another solution you can use is: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/344161/how-to-create-a-grid-with-customized-labels-in-qgis