# Creating new field considering duplicate and numeric values in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, qgis-expression

I'd like to create a new field considering duplicate and numeric values.

For example, I have an attribute table with duplicate values in the `"field1"` and numeric values in the `"field2"`. I'd like to create a `"field3"` in which there are the suffix `_1`, `_2`...on the `"field1"` attributes, when they are duplicates and when `"field2" > 0`.

In case `"field2" = 0` or not duplicated value in the `"field1"` -> `"field3"="field1"`.

The suffix should not be set randomly, but following the spatial direction (or left or right); and for each group of duplicated values.

Before:

[image: Before1]

[image: Before2]

After:

[image: After]

Any suggestion to use a string in the field calculator to do this in QGIS?

Comment: For the directional ordering, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/344161/how-to-create-a-grid-with-customized-labels-in-qgis/344212#344212

Comment: I've seen this answer, but i don't understand how can i adapt it to my case study. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can try the following expression:

```sql
with_variable(
    'my_array',
    array_agg(
        $geometry,
        group_by:="field1",
        filter:="field2">0,
        order_by:=x($geometry)
        ),
    CASE
        WHEN array_find(@my_array, $geometry)=-1
        THEN to_string("field1")
        ELSE to_string("field1") || to_string(array_find(@my_array, $geometry) + 1)
    END
    )
```

A short explanation:

`array_agg` takes all geometries into an array with the same value in `"field1"` (the `GROUP_BY`), without the ones having a 0 in `"field2"` and order it by the easting value(x). In the `CASE WHEN` expression it will proof, if the current value (geometry) is in the array, if yes, it will be added by a position value from the array, if not, it will be nothing added. You may have to play around with the conditions a bit to get the result you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works! In this code, i don't understand where is the condition where "not duplicated value in the "field1" has been set for not to take the suffix ("field1"='c' example). Also, i don't understand where you set "_" before the suffix number 1,2,3. Thanks.

Comment: to set the suffix you should change: ELSE to_string("field1")  || '_' || to_string(array_find(@my_array,$geometry)+1) the 'c' is in fact a problem...

Comment: about the second string....maybe, we can adding a condition not duplicated value in the "field1" in the row -> filter:="field2">0 ?
I'm thinking -> filter:="field2">0 and count_distinct("id","field1")>1,....it should work

Comment: In this case, we are considering the 'x' spatial direction [order_by:=x($geometry))]. 
If there isn't a prevalent direction (x or y), and the points are positioned along a not regular route (presence of curves and intersections); is there a solution to order these points considering the street direction? Thanks a lot!

Comment: yes I think that is possible if you have the direction under your control, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25337/qgis-calculate-distance-of-point-along-a-line