# Creating script to automatically create virtual layers with alphanumeric labels for shapefile grids in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, labeling, vector-layer, grids-graticules, virtual-layer

I have many grids in shapefile format. Adding alphanumeric labels to them can be done through using a virtual layer SQL query as found in this thread: [Creating GRID with customized labels in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/344161/how-to-create-a-grid-with-customized-labels-in-qgis), which works well with some small tweaks for me.

I would like to script creating these automatically, which will save me a lot of time, but I am running into problems. Here is my code:

```py
from qgis.core import (QgsProject, QgsLayoutExporter, QgsApplication)

#get a list of all the layer names
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
mygroup = root.findGroup("Site Locations")
layer_list= mygroup.findLayers()
layer_list = [layer.name() for layer in mygroup.children()]

#list the layers
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers()

#looping code making a virtual layer for each layer
i = 0
for layer in layers:
    site = layer_list[i]
    vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("?query= select *, char(r+64) || ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY r) as newID from (SELECT *,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY round( ST_minY(geometry)/0.000002) desc) as r FROM layer ORDER BY round(ST_minY(geometry)/0.000002)  DESC, round( ST_minX(geometry)/0.000002)  ASC)", site+"_vl", "virtual")
    
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
    i = i + 1
```

This code will create virtual layers, which are all named properly - but each of the files is empty and missing their source. This is the original source URI that is shown when clicking to repair the source:

> ````
> OVER(PARTITION BY r) as newID from (SELECT *,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER
> BY round( ST_minY(geometry)/0.000002) desc) as r FROM layer ORDER BY
> round(ST_minY(geometry)/0.000002)  DESC, round(
> ST_minX(geometry)/0.000002)  ASC)```
> ````

I assume that the code is using the query instead of the shapefile as the source of the layer - how do I go about setting the proper source layer while running the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not listing layer names, and you dont update the SQL query for each row so it is trying to query a layer named `layer`.

Try inserting the correct layer name using an f string for each iteration:

```py
...
layer = [layer.name() for layer in  QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]
    
for layer in layers:
    site = layer_list[i]
    vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(f"?query= select *, char(r+64) || ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY r) as newID from (SELECT *,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY round( ST_minY(geometry)/0.000002) desc) as r FROM {layer} ORDER BY round(ST_minY(geometry)/0.000002)  DESC, round( ST_minX(geometry)/0.000002)  ASC)", site+"_vl", "virtual")
    ...
```